# How can I edit "/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.nfsd.plist" In Catalina?

Tags: catalina, recovery, plist

I need to edit this file to allow Kodi access to my NFS shares. Before Catalina, I was able to go into recovery mode and disable SiP, make the change and re-enable it.

I just upgraded to 10.15.3 and this method no longer works. I read somewhere that the edit needs to be done through terminal from within the recovery mode but I have no idea how to do this.

If anyone can help, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using Xcode?

Comment: I've never used xcode before. I'd like to avoid downloading an 8 gig program to add a single line to 1 plist file, but I suppose if there's no other way, I'll do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quit all apps!

Boot to Recovery Mode **either** with <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> (while booting) **or** in normal GUI mode from within the shell (Terminal):

```
sudo nvram "recovery-boot-mode=unused"
sudo reboot
```

The two *sudo* commands will reboot your Mac immediately to Recovery Mode without further user interaction (i.e. **no** <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> **shortcut necessary while rebooting**)

In Recovery Mode you are already super user: no `sudo`  required and thus not even included in the base system. The security measures introduced with El Capitan (SIP) and Catalina (read-only system volume) are not effective.

In Recovery Mode open Terminal (menu bar > Utilities > Terminal), mount the volume in read mode:

```
mount -uw /Volumes/[name_of_main_volume]
```

Example with the default name *Macintosh HD*:

```
mount -uw /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD
```

Then enter:

```
/Volumes/[name_of_main_volume]/usr/bin/nano /Volumes/[name_of_main_volume]/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.nfsd.plist
```

Example with the default name *Macintosh HD*:

```
/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/usr/bin/nano /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.nfsd.plist
```

Replace

```
        <array>
            <string>/sbin/nfsd</string>
        </array>
```

with (here I assume you are following the instructions [here](https://kodi.wiki/view/NFS#NFS_sharing_from_OS_X) and want to add ***-N*** to the plist)

```
        <array>
            <string>/sbin/nfsd</string>
            <string>-N</string>
        </array>
```

and hit  <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> to write the changes to disk and  <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.

Enter

```
nvram -d recovery-boot-mode #according to user3439894 and other users you don't have to execute this command
reboot
```

to reboot normally.

Comment: In my experience, `nvram -d recovery-boot-mode` isn't really necessary as `sudo nvram "recovery-boot-mode=unused"` doesn't write a persistent entry.  I use the latter all the time and then from Recovery Mode just use `reboot` and it always boots back to a normal mode. Subsequent normal reboots work as expected without having to use  `nvram -d recovery-boot-mode` after having used `sudo nvram "recovery-boot-mode=unused"`.

Comment: @user3439894 I know, but I haven't been able to test the 2nd last step properly. It doesn't hurt though.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I will test this later today when I get back from work and report back. However, yesterday when I tried some stuff out, I couldn't use sudo. It told me command not found.

Comment: The file can be modified in recovery mode, but resets back to defaults on the next boot. Attempted twice, the second time I read the change back, and it still is reverted.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [@klanomath's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/381188/32815), disable SIP, but make sure you mount `/Volumes/Macintosh HD` with read write options inside the recovery mode:

```
mount -uw /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD
```

You can then continue with the remaining steps to edit the file.

Then generate and tag new APFS System Snapshot as follows:

1. Create snapshot:

   ```
   sudo /System/Library/Filesystem/apfs.fs/Contents/Resources/apfs_systemsnapshot -s "SnapshotName" -v /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD
   ```
2. Tag snapshot for next boot:

   ```
   sudo /System/Library/Filesystem/apfs.fs/Contents/Resources/apfs_systemsnapshot -r "SnapshotName" -v /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD
   ```

Finally enable SIP and reboot.

Should probably work.
Cheers

Comment: Unfortunately, no dice on macOS Big Sur 11.5.1; the changes aren't retained on reboot. Any ideas?