# "fs_snapshot_create: Operation not permitted" when trying to generate new system snapshot on M1 Mac

Tags: big-sur, recovery, launchd, plist, apple-silicon

I follow the instructions in [How can I edit "/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.nfsd.plist" In Catalina?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/381182/how-can-i-edit-system-library-launchdaemons-com-apple-nfsd-plist-in-catalina/394746#394746) but failed in generate and tag new APFS System Snapshot.

```
/System/Library/Filesystem/apfs.fs/Contents/Resources/apfs_systemsnapshot
-s "SnapshotName" -v /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD
```

return with "fs_snapshot_create: Operation not permitted"

same instruction succeed with Intel Mac on macOS 11.4

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! As of macOS El Captain 10.11, no processes may change anything, not even Apple's own processes in `/System` `/bin` `/sbin` `/usr` `/var`. You have to switch off the system integrity protection beforehand, but unfortunately I can only advise against it.

Comment: The post you link to uses `sudo`, could this be the issue?

Comment: @nohillside sudo is not required in recovery mode terminal  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406345/sudo-is-missing-on-recovery-terminal

Comment: @lwfWcf But you didn't mention that you wanted to do it in recovery mode.

Comment: @DarwinOSX it mentioned in the link post, my intention is to edit "/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.nfsd.plist", generate APFS Snapshot is just the method.

Comment: But in the linked post it says that the system integrity protection in recoveryOS must first be switched off.  In normal operation then the system partition must be ejected and then the command you executed above with `sudo` . It was nowhere mentioned to work in recoveryOS. By the way, I've already written something about it, but my post was deleted by a moderator for some reason.

Comment: @DarwinOSX If you don't operate in recovery mode, after you reboot the file would be revert to snapshot version, so it would be no reason to operate in normal mode. About your deleted post, can you post to a place like a github gist and comment the link?

Comment: I've undeleted the comment DarwinOSX refered to.